# Need to track unwanted file downloads

Tags: api, search, tracking, anti-piracy

I'm looking to track how many people on the web have made my software program file available for download without my permission.

I've thought of searching for my product name and file size to catch possible thieves.

Do you think a web search API is the best way forward?

EDIT: I plan to use the detection data for survey purposes.

Comment: I've seen this happen to some of the software I have on my site. These content generation google adclick whore sites create pages with a download link to my app. All I do is in httaccess make sure the referer is my site and if it isn't I send a 404. Alot of them don't bother wasting their own hosting for space and bandwidth and instead choose to leach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are web analytics companies which could probably help you more than a roll-your-own solution. Consider the companies that big music and film vendors use, or check with the Business Software Alliance.

Ultimately, you are chasing your tail if you are looking to thwart piracy with the results of this kind of activity. However, if you are steadfast that you must try to understand what is going on, you need professional (web analytic) help. There are so many variations out there that you need someone experienced in tracking this kind of information, since you could easily get a false sense of security, or an inflated sense of activity.

Answer (score 2):

No. This ultimately doesn't help you. What are you going to do? Send them emails tellings them to buy your software? Sounds like a spam filter will get it.

I would suggest in prevention rather than detection. A registration or activation process is pretty popular and reasonably successful, though if you have an amazing app it won't stop the really bad people from hacking it, however it will make it much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I plan to use the data for surveying piracy. Please see my edited question.